# How to use string in map?

Tags: c++, string, stl

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multimap<char,string> m1;


    m1.insert(pair<char,string>('A','def'));
    m1.insert(pair<char,string>('B','ghi'));
    m1.insert(pair<char,string>('C','jkl'));


    multimap<char,string>::iterator it;
    cout<<"The elements of m1 are:"<<endl;
    cout<<"\tKEY\tVALUE\n"<<endl;

    for(it=m1.begin();it!=m1.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<'\t'<<it->first
        <<'\t'<<it->second<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;


}
```

I expect the output to  A def 
But I found error. How to correct it?

MapMulti.cpp    [Error] invalid user-defined conversion from 'int' to 'const std::basic_string&' [-fpermissive]

MapMulti.cpp    [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Comment: Note the difference between `'` and `"`

Comment: `I found error` well, the compiler seems to report an error, and I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 1):

```
    m1.insert(pair<char,string>('A',"def"));
    m1.insert(pair<char,string>('B',"ghi"));
    m1.insert(pair<char,string>('C',"jkl"));
```

strings  literals  are double quoted "likethis" but chars are 's'